# Sorting Core Data entities by two dependent attributes

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nssortdescriptor

Let's say I have a Core Data entity with two NSNumber attributes: `value1` and `value2`.

I want to construct a `NSFetchedResultsController` so I can display my attributes in a table view. The table view should be sorted by `totalValue` witch is calculated by summing `value1` and `value2`.

```
totalValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([value1 intValue] + [value2 intValue])];
```

`totalValue` is not stored in the database because it easily be derived from `value1` and `value2`.

**I can sort the `NSFetchedResultsController` by two independent attributes, but how do I sort it with two dependent attributes like sorting by `totalValue`, the combination of `value1` and `value2`?**

I can subclass `NSManagedObject` but can I create a `NSSortDescriptor` so it sorts on a method in my subclassed `NSManagedObject`?

I know I could easily store the `totalValue` in the database, but what if I wanted to sort locations based on distance from the users location? Than storing the distance wouldn't be an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily just declare total value as a method in your object. You can also use transient values, that means that value is not found in the database.
Then you just make a sort descriptor.

Quite simple to use, and used a lot to sort

Answer (score -1):

If i were you, i will add totalValue as a new attribute for me entity so your entities will be able to be order by value1 and/or value2 and/or totalValue.